# What's the difference between .db and .sqlite files?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I had a look into a program's folder in Program Files of the Windows directory and I found that it has a lot of files with .db extension. I opened one with notepad and I saw that the first string in the file is sqlite 3. What is the difference between files ended with db and those with sqlite extensions ?

Comment: What program is it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808499/sqlite-extension-name

Answer (score 7):

There needn't be a difference in the file format. File format is totally unrelated to the extension it is given. For good practice, we all agreed they *should* match so that we can identify files and their formats by their extension.

However there is nothing that will keep developers or users from using deviant extensions for established file formats.

Some use `.db`, others like to use `.sqlite`. Hell, if they want to use `.abc` (though highly unlikely) for their files, they can. It's just a matter of opening the file with the right program.